# spss count all cells that are not empty

Tags: excel, spss

I am fairly new to SPSS, and I am test a file brought in from Excel into SPSS that has roughly 100 columns (variable name in first row) with some data in each row. What I would like to check is that if any data from any of the cells was dropped. I am trying to compare my "count" function in excel to whatever is possible in SPSS. If there are other ways to make sure no data was dropped?

Comment: What would cause rows to be dropped? I should think that determining if any blank rows were added due to an errant [xlCellTypeLastCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) would be of a higher concern.

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps easier to count all empty cells and see if that's zero for all rows. Note that in SPSS, empty cells virtually always indicate [system missing values](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-missing-values-tutorial/#sysmis). Now if your first variable is `x1` and your last variable is `x5`, running

```
count check = x1 to x5 (sysmis).

sort cases by check(d).
```

computes a new variable, `check`, holding the number of system missing values per row and sorts your rows according to it, thus moving the rows with most system missing values (if any) to the top of your file.

Alternatively, you could use the [nmiss function](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-missing-values-functions/#nmiss). This includes user missing values too but these won't be present just after importing from Excel.

Comment: Thank you for your response, to clarify a little more about the data I am dealing with, say I have 5 columns and 10 rows, with data in some cells but not all, and some are numeric and some are string. What I want to check and confirm is that the same amount of cells are populated with data in SPSS as from the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to set two. Assuming your Value column is  A than
this what goes in column B =ISBLANK(A2). It will bring true or false values
Then second column C:
=IF(B2=TRUE,COUNTIF(B:B,B2 ),0)